# How to tell if an SQL transaction in rails is successful?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

I was wondering how you tell if an sql transaction was successful in rails, does it return true or something like that. Or does the code just error on fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activerecord will throw `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception when a transaction will fail. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html for more information.